# A basic question: what is accelerating voltage?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, terminology

Or would it be acceleration voltage? Acceleration sounds like it makes more sense, but my paper says accelerating.

What are possible ways you could go about calculating it?

Comment: Context? Also, is this what you're referring to? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_voltage

Comment: What paper are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

"accelerating voltage" is the common term for the potential difference that accelerates a charge. The use comes from electron guns.

The rule is 1V accelerates an electron by 1eV kinetic energy.
You can work it out in general from Maxwell's equations.
Then, naturally, there are shortcuts depending on the overall geometry of the situation.

Can you be more specific?